# Titanium Mobile Framework. Access server through VPN from an iPad app

Tags: ipad, httpclient, titanium, vpn

In an iPad application, with VPN active and connected, the HttpClient can't access to a server in intranet, but I can access to same url when I access from Safari iPad.

The property Titanium.Network.networkTypeName shows "WIFI" or "MOBILE" but nothing related with a VPN connection.

Can anyone help me ? It's mandatory for my application access server through VPN.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got more info about my problem, actually the VPN wasn't the problem, the HTTClient uses the current device connection channel, that is, uses the VPN network and there is access to intranet server.

The problem was related with WAS server, when user is authenticated successfully against LDAP (using JAAS standard) then Connection was lost, when authentication failed then communications was OK and correct message was show to user, but when LDAP returned a valid authentication something made lost the communication channel.

I'm not sure about the "real" problem, but the solution was to add the HTTP header to request:
"Connection": "Keep-Alive"

This solves the problem.